# Idle Can't Bind to Ports

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

I have been trying to learn python on my raspberry pi.  For some reason my Idle program wont run with subprocesses. When I try to launch it from the menu, I get this error message:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GICE4pX.png]

To launch it I have to type `sudo idle -n &`. This is very inconvenient, and I have no idea why it happens. I installed a fresh copy of Raspbian, and the problem persisted. I have used Python in the past without this happening, and I'm at a loss here. I have a RasPi 2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that IDLE uses a TCP Port (a network port), 8833 as far as I know, to connect to the python server. This port is not available. This could have some reasons. Perhaps there is no network running. I assume that is not the case. The Port might already be in use. Perhaps IDEL is still running. Give it a try

```
ps -ef | grep idel
```

Or, you started Idle stopped it and started it at once. It lasts a while to release the network port. This may take up to a minute. The last reason I could imagine is that, the port is used by another program. 
Try

```
netstat -tlnp |grep python
```

If the command outputs a line or more. Then there is most likely an idle process still running. Perhpas started by the autorunner.

```
netstat -tlnp
```

If you find port 8833 in a line of the output and the last command did no find a result then, another programm blocks port 8833. It it is a name process it's name is shown at the end of the line.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested.  Here is what I got: http://imgur.com/gallery/UvsCBWg/new (This image thing is hard.)

Comment: It looks ok. I edited the answer to a broader search.